# Is there way to put text files into database (SQLite)?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am sorry if my question was vague. So basically I have bunch of text files which contain variety of lengths of texts.

I was wondering if there is a way to 'put' the text files into database.

The important thing is that I need to preserve the name of the text file and the contents in the text files.

Even though I know basic commands of sql, I have no experience in applying this language to something practical.

Thank you !!

Comment: You can save the path in database; Which is the best technique

Answer (score 0):

```
sqlite3 newdb
```

To open an existing sqlite database called 'olddb':

```
sqlite3 olddb
```

Once you create a new db or open an existing one, you can import the data. 
First use CREATE TABLE syntax to create the table(s) to hold your data, if 
is does not already exist.

Then set the separator/delimiter in your text file(s):

```
.separator STRING
```

where STRING is the separator character.

Then import the data from a text file FILE into a table called TABLE:

```
.import FILE TABLE
```

See this for details on the commands available for the cmd line tool:

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Ref: http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/importing-text-or-text-delimited-file-td33735.html

Comment: I created one column table, and set the delimiter as "."
I put my text file into the same directory as where I started the sqlite3. But when I try .import FILE  TABLE, it says "cannot open FILE".   Do you know any reason why??

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a table with two columns. The first column is NAME, which is used to store the name of the file. The data type of this column is VARCHAR. You can set the maximum length of the VARCHAR into the appropriate value. This data type supports character of variable length, up the maximum length that you specify. The second column is CONTENT, which is used to store the content of the file. The type of this column is BLOB. This data type supports binary data of huge length (the exact length depends on the database that you are using, but to give an idea, the size is around gigabytes).

After that, you can create an application that uses JDBC to insert your files into this table.